# check duplicate on Access Database before inserting

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Been awake for finding solution on this one. Is there a way on how to check duplicate on my Access Database before inserting the values and giving me a message that there's already a record. Here is my code and I don't know where to and how to check it

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

            If txtCat.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please Complete the Information Needed")
                txtCat.Focus()


            Else
                If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Add Category?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "WARNING") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

                    Dim DBC As New OleDbCommand
                    With DBC
                        .Connection = conn
                        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_category(Category) VALUES('" & txtCat.Text & "')"
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End With
                    MsgBox("Category Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "SUCCESS")

                    Call CatList()

                    txtCat.Text = ""
                    txtCat.Enabled = False
                    btnSave.Enabled = False

                    Call CatCombo()


                End If
            End If

        End Sub
```

This is my first time to check a duplicate that's why I don't know how to

Comment: If you dont want duplicates in your database, setup a unique index so the database will not allow duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_category(Category) VALUES('" & txtCat.Text & "') WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select '8' from tbl_category  where Category = + " & txtCat.Text & + "
```

Of course this is not best practice. This format is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: it gives me an error, "Query input must contain at least one table or query."

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/exists-access-t1914818.html   This talks about setting up a dummy table that will return a row and will allow you to get around that exception.